# How to make my player die when it touch enemy (die when other object is touching it)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-animate

So i made my first game on Adobe Animate CC (using AS 3.0). The concept of the game is **a zombie who haunted & surrounding by living creature (people), so if the people is touch the zombie (my player), the zombie will die. Also, the people/enemy will move randomly in the area.**

Currently, my progress so far is done with making the zombie movement (also, for the movement is like you play DOTA 2. You click your mouse on specific area, and the zombie would be go to that specific area too).

Here's my code so far:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
 
crewMC.stop();
var moveX:Number = crewMC.x;
var moveY:Number = crewMC.y;
 
crewMC.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCrew);
 
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickArea);
 
function clickArea(e:MouseEvent):void{
    moveX = mouseX;
    moveY = mouseY; 
}
 
function moveCrew(e:Event):void{
    var ob:Object = e.currentTarget;
    var distX:Number = moveX-ob.x;
    var distY:Number = moveY-ob.y;
    var dist:Number = Math.sqrt(distX*distX+distY*distY);
    if (dist < 10){
        //iddle
        ob.gotoAndStop(1);
    }else{
        //run
        ob.gotoAndStop(2);
        var rad:Number = Math.atan(distY/distX);
        if (distX>=0){
            ob.scaleX = 1;
            ob.rot = rad*180/Math.PI;
        } else {
            ob.scaleX = -1;
            ob.rot = rad*180/Math.PI+180;
        }
        ob.x += 5 * Math.cos(ob.rot*Math.PI/180);
        ob.y += 5 * Math.sin(ob.rot*Math.PI/180);
    }
}
```

So can you guys please help me? My struggle is:

1. **How can I add the people/enemy move randomly on the area?**
2. **How can I add death effect when the zombie is touched by enemy?**

Thank you guys! Every response from you is really appreciate!

Comment: For question 1, you can assign the enemy to move randomly by using Math.random(), then add it to their x,y coordinates. For tweening purposes, I highly recommend Greensock. For question 2, you'd have to check for hitTestObject every frame and check for enemy contact with your player. If hitTestObject returns true(collision), then you can either play an animation sequence on your player movieclip that represents your death animation.

Comment: Hi bro, do you have any idea how the code is? I'm very newbie here, sorry.

Comment: Maybe remove the "game-maker" tag if this is an AS3 question and not GameMaker. Random movement can be done much like your existing code, but picking the destination point as `x - 100 + Math.random() * 200` or alike once the object reaches the destination. Collision checking can be done using `hitTestObject`.